# After list checking getting wrong value

Tags: c#, list

So I have creating list and adding to it elements, later I want to read them.And it is not not working properly. In my case if title true and  checkbox.checked true, it should return true value. But it giving me false.  Here is my code:

```
foreach (var part in config.Parts)
{
    if (part.Title == "chapter2") 
    {                                       //true
        checkBox1.Checked = part.Checked;
    }                                       //true         
    if (part.Title == "chapter3")
    {                                    
        checkBox2.Checked = part.Checked;
    }
  }                                  //false
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The source code you provided is not sufficient to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Your question is really unclear - you've put "random false" on a line with just an opening brace. Please edit your question to include a [mcve] so we can see what you mean and reproduce it.

Comment: And I don't understand why instead of copy/pasting people try to re-write the code in this rich editor. Your source code has an opening bracket instead of a closing bracket at the bottom.

Comment: It is not only about the code. It is about the clarity of the question. As for me, I haven't understood anything. What is the "final answer", "random becomes false", "wrong value". Please, operate with on-topic programming terms in order to make other people understand you.

Comment: Guys, when my if statement check what is my title and check box status and getting true value, at the end of all process in if's , it throws me that it is false, but it should be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it to switch case to make it look better and more manageable.

```
foreach (var part in config.Parts)
{
    switch(part.Title){
        case "chapter2" : 
            checkBox1.Checked = part.Checked;
        break;
        case "chapter3" : 
            checkBox2.Checked = part.Checked;
        break;
        default : 
            throw new Exception("Case not handled");
        break;
    }
  }
```

And remember, you are running it in a loop. Your checkbox might be overwritten if you get two `part.Title == "some chapter number"`

Comment: That´s not an answer to the OPs question, merely a design-improvement (if even anything).

Comment: But in my case will this work if I want to use both chapters, not only one

Comment: @Mantas because you are in for loop, so you will be checking for Title of each part. And whichever matches, it will move on to the next one.

Comment: @Yahya yes I know this, how to change this?